# Alternatives to LAStools lasthin?

Tags: qgis, lidar, software-recommendations, lidr

I have a classified LAS file that I would like to further filter the ground points to only include the lowest z values based on a variety of grid sizes.

Is there an alternative tool available that works similarly to `lasthin` from `LAStools`?

Comment: Curious. What the point about not using `lasthin` if it already does the job?

Comment: @ThomasG77 From what I understand lasthin is under the license, which I don't have, and I am working with larger datasets (100 million+ points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lidR` you can do

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile, filter = "-keep_class 2")
thinned <- decimate_points(las, lowest(1))
plot(thinned)
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I am seeing that LidR deciminate_points has three algorithms:  random, homogenized and highest. but no lowest?

Comment: It has `lowest` in 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You may try PDAL utility `pdal_translate` with filter options like at https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/thinning/thinning.html

```
pdal translate in.laz \
out-thin.laz \
sample --filters.sample.radius=20
```

You can also use CloudCompare using [command line](https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Command_line_mode) option `-SS` (for subsampling) or via [GUI](https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Edit%5CSubsample)